# Функция preg_match. Работа сразу с несколькими переменными.

Tags: php

Я уже давненько использую такой код:

```
if (preg_match("/^слово/", $peremennaya)) {
```

Она производит проверку наличия "слово" в начале переменной `$peremennaya`. Но как сделать одновременную массовую проверку? Т.е., допустим, мне надо одновременно проверить наличие слова "поиск" в переменной `$get`, а также слова "вперед" в переменной `$santex` и слова "цена" в переменной `$korzina`.

Думаю, здесь нужно работать со скобками "{". Но хотелось бы услышать мнение знающиx людей...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несколько `preg_match` в одном условии

```
if (
    preg_match("/^поиск/", $get) &&
    preg_match("/^вперед/", $santex) &&
    preg_match("/^цена/", $korzina)
) {
    // Какой-то код...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) У вас проверка не "наличия", а "начала с" 
2) На сколько знаю - то что вы хотите, так как вы предполагает - очень не советую, но можно так:

```
preg_match(
  '/слово1[^\v]*\v[^\v]*слово2[^\v]*\v[^\v]*слово3/',
  join('\v', array( $var1, $var2, $var3) )
);
```

`\v` - вертикальная табуляция

Comment: В любом случае проверяется наличие))

Comment: Спасибо, но буду использовать вариант KiTE, там более аккуратно код выглядит. Хотя, потом посмотрю по скорости выполнения, наверное...

Comment: Не, не в любом случае. Если у тебя регулярка `/^слово/`, то она найдется в строках `"слово №1"` и `"слово №2"` и не найдется в - `"первое слово"` и `"второе слово"`. А, если будет просто `/слово/`, то подойдут все 4-е варианта.

Comment: @nick777, я же написал в ответе - массовую проверку можно сделать только склеив строки, тривиальные варианты не рассматривал...